# When is an answer not an answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/can-someone-help-identify-an-old-ish-fantasy-novel-about-magicians-that-have-a-ch/4927#4927) answer to the question [Can someone help identify an old-ish fantasy novel about magicians that have a characteristic animal form?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/can-someone-help-identify-an-old-ish-fantasy-novel-about-magicians-that-have-a-ch/) earlier as **"not an answer"** as I felt that an answer to a (story identification) question which the answerer starts with:

> I know it isn't the right books

and then continues on to describe a book which has similar concepts but is (as the answerer admits) not the book that the question is asking after.

Quite clearly fits the definition of:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It
>   should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted
>   altogether.

Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree it works better as a comment on the post and I have converted it.

Also, be sure that you're being gentle with new users who show some reasonable potential -- leave lots of comments explaining what they should be doing. Otherwise, we're turning off users and stunting the site's growth.

Comment: +1 for being gental.

Answer (score 2):

I consider this a borderline case. I hesitated, but decided leaving it as an answer because there hasn't been a plausible answer and the asker might be conflating two books. So in this sense, it's a tentative, partial answer. I'm inclined to be more tolerant of weak answers on identification questions, because far-fetched guesses do sometimes turn out to be right. I can see the case for keeping this in a comment too.

Comment: This was exactly how I felt.  IMO sometimes it's just better to downvote an undesirable question rather than unilaterally convert it to a comment.   Because downvotes come from the community at large, while comment conversion can only stem from high-powered users.